# Are there any Mongoose validation libraries?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to mongoDB and mongoose in fact I am new to Javascript as a whole. As a result of this I'm not sure of how I should go about sanitizing my data.

I was wondering if there are any libraries with custom validation functions that take care of at least some generic dangers one should watch out for. Also it would be nice if it already had commonly used validation such as email, or character length.

Comment: http://plugins.mongoosejs.com/

Comment: Oh wow that is nice, but it doesn't really answer what I should look for when sanitizing for Mongoose to prevent evil injection queries.

Answer (score -1):

Hi there are many libraries for mongoose schema validation.some of are listed below.
https://github.com/leepowellcouk/mongoose-validator,

https://github.com/SamVerschueren/node-mongoose-validator

both are good library for mongoose validation..Also mongoose provide custom logic for validation.

More if you want to create custom logic then https://github.com/chriso/validator.js helpful to you.

for email validation i use this

```
const emailRegex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/

email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    unique: true,
    required: 'Email address is required',
    validate: {
      validator: (email)=> {
        return emailRegex.test(email)
      },
      message: '{VALUE} is not a valid email'
    },
    match: [emailRegex, 'Please fill a valid email address']

  }
```